# React test react-truncate using enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I am using [react-truncate](https://github.com/One-com/react-truncate) for a project. The basic setup with a expand-collapse and ellipsis is expected to be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Truncate from 'react-truncate';

class ReadMore extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

        this.state = {
            expanded: false,
            truncated: false
        };

        this.handleTruncate = this.handleTruncate.bind(this);
        this.toggleLines = this.toggleLines.bind(this);
    }

    handleTruncate(truncated) {
        if (this.state.truncated !== truncated) {
            this.setState({
                truncated
            });
        }
    }

    toggleLines(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            expanded: !this.state.expanded
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            children,
            more,
            less,
            lines
        } = this.props;

        const {
            expanded,
            truncated
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Truncate
                    lines={!expanded && lines}
                    ellipsis={(
                        <span> <a href='#' onClick={this.toggleLines}>{more}</a></span>
                    )}
                    onTruncate={this.handleTruncate}
                >
                    {children}
                </Truncate>
                {!truncated && expanded && (
                    <span> <a href='#' onClick={this.toggleLines}>{less}</a></span>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReadMore.defaultProps = {
    lines: 3,
    more: 'Read more',
    less: 'Show less'
};

ReadMore.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.node,
    lines: PropTypes.number
};

export default ReadMore;
```

I want to test the expand-collapse functionality in my project using enzyme, so far I can verify the basic setup and default behavior:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ReadMore />); // where above code is defined
expect(wrapper.state('expanded')).to.equal(false); // passes
```

But am stuck with how to stimulate the `expand click` behavior on this, I tried

`wrapper.toggleLines;` // returns undefined.

The debug output `console.log(wrapper.debug());` is

```
<div>
  <Truncate lines={3} ellipsis={{...}} onTruncate={[Function: bound handleTruncate]} trimWhitespace={false} />
</div>
```

I am not sure how to access the `onClick` property of the `Read more` span

Basically what I am looking for is something like:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ExpandCollapse />); // where above code is defined
expect(wrapper.state('expanded')).to.equal(false); // passes
//simulate onclick on Expand button 
expect(wrapper.state('expanded')).to.equal(true); // should pass
//then trigger onclick on Collapse button
expect(wrapper.state('expanded')).to.equal(false); // should pass
```

Any ideas on how to proceed on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `onClick` target is a sub-component/inside a sub-component you will have to use `mount` instead since `shallow` renders only one level deep.

For example, it could be something like this:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Foo onClick={onClick} />); 
wrapper.find('span').simulate('click');
```

Comment: Yep, you will probably have more chance with mount

Comment: Great! Its always something simple that i tend to miss :) thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `simulate`?

From the [README](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) of enzyme:

> ```
> const wrapper = shallow(<Foo onButtonClick={onButtonClick} />);
> wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
> ```

---

The span being in a sub-component, this might not be enough.
You may have more chance with something like that:

```
wrapper.find(Truncate).shallow().find('span').simulate('click');
```

I haven't done this yet, so I'm not 100% sure it works.

Comment: So I tried doing as you suggested, but I am getting `ReferenceError: Truncate is not defined` I then tried `wrapper.find('div').dive().find(Truncate).shallow().find('span').simulate('click');` since its wrapped in a `div` to which I got `TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components`. I don't understand why it cant find Truncate, debug shows its defined

Comment: Did you import Truncate in your test file?

Comment: Yeah I did and all its helper const as well